# JQuery focusOut issue in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small problem with `focusout` function in IE.

I have two fields with the same class and I wrote an empty validation code in jQuery for that class with `focusout`.

While I focus out of a field which is empty it shows alert and focus to the same field.

While doing that focus, It shows me alert again and again b'coz of the same class.

What to do?

**JS:**

```
$(".emptyValidate").focusout(function() {    
var currFocusOut = $(this).attr("inText");
    if($(this).val() == ""){            
      alert(currFocusOut+" should not be Empty");
      document.getElementById(currFocusOut).focus();
    }
});
```

**Markup :**

```
<input type="text" inText="Name" id="Name" class="emptyValidate "/>
<input type="text" inText="Phone" id="Phone" class="emptyValidate "/>
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/dZDPC/)

```
$(".emptyValidate").focusout(function () {
    var currFocusOut = $(this).attr("id");
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        alert(currFocusOut + " should not be Empty");
        $('#'+currFocusOut).focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: Bro,same issue.Its not working.its just work like the above code.

Comment: which version of IE are you using ??

Comment: Internet explorer version 8

Comment: i also don't why..i am using 8.0.7600.16385

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34740/discussion-between-tushar-gupta-and-raja)

Comment: hay i am in chat..come to chat room.

Comment: Bro thats also coming wrong.its not focusing me again to that field.

Comment: i am in chat room.Can u able to come.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `blur function` like,

```
$(".emptyValidate").blur(function() {    
    var currFocusOut = $(this).attr("inText");
    if($(this).val() == ""){            
      alert(currFocusOut+" should not be Empty");
      document.getElementById(currFocusOut).focus();
    }
});
```

Read [blur()](http://api.jquery.com/data)

Or, custom attribute `inText` may not work, so you can use `data` in `jquery` like

```
<input type="text" data-inText="Name" id="Name" class="emptyValidate "/>
<input type="text" data-inText="Phone" id="Phone" class="emptyValidate "/>

$(".emptyValidate").focusout(function() {  // use blur if not works  
    var currFocusOut = $(this).data("inText");
    if($(this).val() == ""){            
      alert(currFocusOut+" should not be Empty");
      document.getElementById(currFocusOut).focus();
    }
});
```

Read [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data)

Comment: By using blur also shows me the same error.Before it shows the alert the cursor goes to the next field.It's class also same.So when i am making focus to the before field means it takes that also as the focus or blur function.So only repeatedly alert shows.

Comment: i am getting value by using custom tag as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try inline function like this:

```
<input type="text" inText="Name" id="Name" class="emptyValidate"  onfocusout="myFunction(this)"/>
<input type="text" inText="Phone" id="Phone" class="emptyValidate"  onfocusout="myFunction(this)"/>
function myFunction(el){
    var currFocusOut = $(el).attr("inText");
    if($(el).val() == ""){            
      alert(currFocusOut+" should not be Empty");
      document.getElementById(currFocusOut).focus();
    }
}
```